# sticky footer working but with scroll

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I am trying to use the trick [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) to make my footer locked at bottom of the [page](http://yalleshleiron.com/ds/contact/) if I have a short content. It is working but only a small portion of the footer is visible, I still have to scroll to see all of it. Because I am using Wordpress, its getting worse if I logged in, because of the wordpress header, the footer is more deeper. I tried to remove the How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably have padding or margin on `<body>` but without seeing some code we can only guess. How bout a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I didn't add the code because its just the same with the [link](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) I have posted and I don't know what causing the problem and its too long. You can click the "page" in my post to see the page so you can just Inspect the Elements.

Answer (score 0):

Provide absolute height to footer, make the position absolute or fixed and keep the footer block in outermost section as in body tag should be the parent of your footer div. You can check the example of same here http://www.blue-softwares.com/

Comment: Looks like you misinterpreted my post, I said lock at the bottom of the page not screen. They are different.